# Postgres doesn't ignore upper and lower letters

Tags: linux, postgresql

My unix user is `Ru`. And I found I have no privilege. So,I use `\du` and found a role named `ru`.

After I dropped it, I found this secret.

```
postgres=# ALTER role Ru with superuser;
ERROR:  role "ru" does not exist
```

How can I do with this?

I know this is a `badname`.

- -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work!

```
ALTER ROLE 'Ru' WITH SUPERUSER; --whatever privilege you want to give
```

Comment: Thanks.Finally,this dose work. `ALTER ROLE "Ru" WITH SUPERUSER;`